# Loop through a range to fill form

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a program that will create coversheets for projects.

All source data is held on the 'data' tab, and using lookups it is populated on the '1034' tab

Cell P2 on sheet '1034' contains the Project#, and after saving that form to PDF, should be set to the next value in the range of projects in 'data'

Below is what I have so far

```
Sub Generate1034()
   'Select Project # Cell, set value to start
   Range("P2").Value = Range(Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("A3"))

   'Set range on 'data' from A3:(empty cell)
   Range (Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("A3").Select)
   Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

   'Save Parameters
   Application.Worksheets("1034").Range("P2") = Format(x, "000")
   Dim SaveName As String
   SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("P33").Text
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\1034\" & _
       SaveName & ".pdf"\

   'Set P2 to the next value in range
   Range("P2").Value = Range(Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("A3"))

   Loop
 End Sub
```

This is the previous code that it was running on, but I would like to make it a bit more flexible if the size of the range changes.
This would lookup '001' on data, and return the value from colB

```
Sub SaveAs()
   For x = 1 To 5
   Application.Worksheets("1034").Range("P2") = Format(x, "000")
   Dim SaveName As String
   SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("P33").Text
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\1034\" & _
       SaveName & ".pdf"
    Next x
 End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe more details would help. What's Data tab? And I can't see any lookup you are doing.

Comment: Sure, sorry for not being more clear. The data tab(worksheet) houses the information that need to be filled into the form worksheet. I already have Vlookups set to bring over the relevant information once the project# is populated, so none of that information needs to be included in the macro code

Comment: So what is the issue then?

Comment: I need help coding how to populate P2 on the '1034' worksheet from the list provided on the 'data' worksheet